# Change date format of DatePicker in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am just trying to display a date from the DatePicker component in React but it displays it as an Object :

```
startDateOwner: Mon Feb 08 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

How could I display it as 08/02/2021 and as a string?

Here is the code I am using:

```js
const Calendar = ({ startDate, endDate, handleChangeDates }) => (
  <div>
    <label> Beginning date
    <DatePicker 
      name = "startDate"
      selected={startDate}
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onChange={(date)=>handleChangeDates(date, "startDate")}
    />
    </label>
    <label> End date
    <DatePicker
      name = "endDate"
      selected={endDate}
      selectsEnd
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      minDate={startDate}
      onChange={(date)=>handleChangeDates(date, "endDate")}
    />
    </label>
  </div>
```

Thank you !
Julie

Answer (score 2):

React date picker provides a attribute  `dateFormat`

```
<DatePicker 
      name = "startDate"
      selected={startDate}
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onChange={(date)=>handleChangeDates(formatDateFn(date), "startDate")}
      dateFormat="dd/MM/YYYY"  (Use dd/MM/yyyy  if you get error in console)
    />


const formatDateFn = (date) => {
     const selectedDate = new Date(date)
     return selectedDate.getDate() + "/"+ parseInt(selectedDate.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ selectedDate.getFullYear();

}
```

You are welcome! Subodh

Comment: Thank you Subodh ! Now it logs this when I select 10/02/2021 ->  Sat Oct 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

Comment: You can format the date as per your required format. Use the date received in onChange function. I have updated my answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

If you're objective is to just display the date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format, you may use ***moment***

```
moment(date_variable).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```

This would work to display date.

Comment: Where would you add it in this?
<DatePicker 
      name = "startDate"
      selected={startDate}
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onChange={(date)=>handleChangeDates(date, "startDate")}
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      minDate={new Date()}
      placeholderText="Select Start Date"
    />

Comment: On onChange attribute, handle a function which will display the date of your format